# Using pdflatex in windows console

Tags: pdftex

I've got a problem with `pdflatex` on Windows system in console.

My tex file is working fine, when I generate it with TeXWorks. But when I try to generate a PDF file from the command line, it does not recognize my parameters. 
The tex file is placed in the same folder where I start the command:

[image]

The command I try to use is this one:

```
pdflatex -job-name Omn9MRHEeHDTEvvDtS9y.tex
```

But the console does not recognize it as parameter. It asks always for the input file:

[image]

I also tried this commands:

```
pdflatex -job-name=Omn9MRHEeHDTEvvDtS9y.tex
pdflatex -job-name "Omn9MRHEeHDTEvvDtS9y.tex"
pdflatex -job-name="Omn9MRHEeHDTEvvDtS9y.tex"
pdflatex -job-name 'Omn9MRHEeHDTEvvDtS9y.tex'
```

Same result...
Any hint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Oh no, isn't it `pdflatex -jobname ...` ?

Comment: -job-name is wrong, the name of the option is -jobname.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your hints. When I used `pdflatex Omn9MRHEeHDTEvvDtS9y.tex` it worked fine! Thanks!

Comment: and when using --jobname you need two arguments: the new jobname and the name of the file.

Comment: @KJO ah yes, miktex accepts both. But I would stick to --jobname, that works in texlive too (the main problem is naturally the missing argument).

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: the option is `-jobname` or `--jobname`, but not `-job-name`. As pointed out in the comments, `--jobname` requires an argument as well as the file name to be loaded.

Comment: Er, no: `--jobname` requires _one_ argument, but you still have to give the file name to be loaded. If you do just `pdflatex --jobname foo` you are replacing the default `texinput`

Comment: @JosephWright I'm searching for documentation, but in vain. In the pdftex manual I simply found "All options can be specified with one or two dashes and unambiguously abbreviated." Where can I draw enlightment? Other docu: "-jobname name
Use name for the job name, instead of deriving it from the name of the input file." pdftex.man1.pdf